# Python dynamic dictionary size with user input for key

Tags: python, dictionary, raw-input

Input can be up to (but not always) 20 values between 1-99 separated by 'or' that need to be associated with a string. User input will supply both the value and the "label" that should replace that value in a print-to-text-file output. I also can ask the user for the number of values they supply.

For example:
User input:

> 1 or 2 or 10 or 60

Quantity input:

> 4

Label input:

> Today, Two Days, One Month, One Year

Clarification: the input values do not correspond mathematically to the label string itself and are abstract.

> {'1': 'Today',
>    '2': 'Two Days',
>    '10': 'One Month',
>    '60': 'One Year'}

How can I account for user supplied keys and an unknown quantity of pairs?

Comment: You should really try to solve this yourself first, and then post a question with relevant code samples.   This looks like you are just trying to get help with homework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you always know the pairs will align, you don't have to worry about how many there are. Simply split-and-clean, (I'll simply `map` `str.strip` for cleaning...) then [`zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/5014455), then pass to the `dict` type-constructor:

```
>>> in_1 = "1 or 2 or 10 or 60"
>>> in_2 = "Today, Two Days, One Month, One Year"
>>> dict(zip(map(str.strip, in_1.split('or')), map(str.strip, in_2.split(','))))
{'1': 'Today', '2': 'Two Days', '60': 'One Year', '10': 'One Month'}
```

This assumes your input is "well-behaved", so, you can reliably split on `"or"` and commas: `","`.